# Получить ключ зная значение

Tags: python, функции, словари

Нужно **вытащить ключ из словаря**, при условии что пользовательский ввод совпадет со значение словаря

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
}
```

у меня получилось что-то такое, но естественно не работает ничего

```
def shelf_id(shelfs):
person = input('Введите номер документа: ')
for key, value in shelfs.items():
    if person == value:
        return key
```

Изменил код, номер полки теперь пишет корректно, но при любом вводе от пользователя выходит сообщение "Введен несуществующий номер", что изменить, чтобы это сообщение выскакивало только тогда, когда введен номер отсутствующий в словаре?

```
def shelf_id(shelfs):
person = input('Введите номер документа: ')
for key, value in shelfs.items():
    if person in value:
        return print(key)
    else:
        print('Введен несуществующий номер!')
```

Comment: Исправьте табуляции в коде функций. Такой код не скомпилируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if person == value:
```

Нужно просто поменять проверку, поскольку `value` - это список и нужно проверить элемент `person` на вхождение в этот список:

```
if person in value:
```

**UPDATE**:
По изменённому вопросу (кстати, не делайте так, изменения исходного вопроса делают бесполезными уже данные ответы на первоначальный вопрос). Исправьте табуляции и выводите отрицательный ответ после цикла:

```
def shelf_id(shelfs):
    person = input('Введите номер документа: ')
    for key, value in shelfs.items():
        if person in value:
            return print(key)
    print('Введен несуществующий номер!')
```